# Java: getting reference type at runtime

Tags: java

Assume two classes: `Beverage` and `Beer`.

```
public class Beverage { }
public class Beer extends Beverage { }
```

Is there a way in Java how to get both **reference class Name** and **actual class name** stored in memory ?

See the following code:

```
Beverage beverage = new Beer()
classInfo(beverage)

public void classInfo(Object obj) {
    System.out.println("Class saved in memory: " + obj.getClass()); // class Beer
    System.out.println("Reference type: " + ???); // class Beverage
}
```

One solution can be requiring Class in method call, this way I would know the reference type and the actual type stored in memory:

```
public void classInfo(Object obj, Class<?> referenceClass)
```

But I wonder if there in other way in java

**EDIT**: Why I need this ?
In production code for our web app we create requests to database based on Class annotations (ORM). In our code we create extended classes, eg `Beer` exends `Bevarage`. These extended objects have some extra attributes that are calculated. Now we want to save these extended objects back to database, but these extended attributes aren't mapped to any table, so the insert fails.

Comment: Can you please explain *why* you need the declared type in this case? It seems that you're trying the wrong solution to a problem we have no idea about.

Answer (score 1):

There's no such thing as "the reference type" the way your example implies it. You can have a reference to the same object stored in as many variables you want, of all possible types.

The closest to your idea of reference type is the declared type of *one specific* variable, for example your `beverage`, if it was an instance variable, would have a declared type that you can find out by reflection. If, on the other hand, it's a local variable, then its declared type simply doesn't exist at runtime in a way you can find out.